# Change the locale on Eonasdan datetimepicker but not the language

Tags: locale, momentjs, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Let's say I want to change the locale on datetimepicker to be Russian like:

`$("#datePicker2").datetimepicker({ locale:'ru' });`

which changes date time format and other parameteres to Russian, however I don't want the language to be changed unless there's an option as 'lang' or 'language' which I can set the language. based on my search moment.js works the same way but is there any solution or option that I've missed out? thanks.

Comment: If you just want change the format you can use [`format`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) option. I do not fully get what is your issue when changing the locale.

Comment: @VincenzoC my website users can change their locale and also language. let's say somebody's language is English but now moved to Russia and changes the locale to Russian but doesnt want the language of calendar like days and months change to Russian, is that possible?